# Email creates new record in rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I'm not really sure where to start with this one, but here is what I'm looking to do.

Lets say you've registered at a website (yourwebsite.com). Your username/email is joe@shmoe.com.

If you email newrecord@yourwebsite.com, I'd like a new record created by your user (meaning you have to email it from a registered user's email - such as joe@shmoe.com).

I'd also like to add some variables in the email body, that can be set to their respective fields in the new record.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Absolutely doable! But I wouldn't match it to the senders address (joe@shmoe.com), as it is easy to spoof. I'd give every user a unique address they can send their stuff to (like adlfkajlfajlfa@yourwebsite.com). That way your service is not as easily compromised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure is possible - have a look at http://cloudmailin.com/ too - they do all the receiving side of things for you and then just 'post' the email into your application.

Comment: My app is on Heroku, and after doing a little more research I discovered this addon already exists for heroku and seems to be exactly what I need!

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely possible - that functionality is available in basecamp.

I've never done it myself, but looks like [this article](http://jasonseifer.com/2009/04/24/receving-email-with-rails) describes how to process incoming emails in rails. Good luck!